# Word for "stating the obvious?"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or term commonly used to describe the act of stating the obvious (or a person who continually does so)? Example sentences are given for a suitable noun / NP, or verb ... but other relevant suggestions are welcome.

> He constantly states the obvious, he is such a ____.

> She is always ___ing.

Comment: I was going to say 'duh' ...

Comment: I am familiar with many of the *responses* to someone stating the obvious, most of which are not meant to be kind: "Duh," "No duh," "No shit," "No shit, Sherlock," and others.

Comment: Sorry to state the obvious, but for the verb form, what is wrong with “She is always stating the obvious?” :-P

Comment: @PLL I was hoping for something that might be more concise, yet at the same time be somewhat derogatory. I thought there was such a term, but it's becoming apparent there is not.

Comment: pedant?  https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/55598085.jpg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a somewhat insulting noun, "[Captain obvious](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=captain+obvious)" can be used for someone who is always stating the obvious.

[Prolixity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolixity) can be used to describe someone who says *too much*. This may be applicable in some cases.

In addition, [Logorrhoea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logorrhoea_%28linguistics%29) is a term with a similar meaning to prolixity although again the primary meaning is simply *too much* vs. stating the obvious.

Comment: Wow... prolixity. You'll get quizzical looks if you use words like that with people. I'd probably use verbose in conversation.

Comment: @Atømix: I agree that prolixity is probably not in most people's vocabulary (it certainly wasn't in mine until this answer!). Verbosity to me is not the same as stating the obvious, I generally take it to mean "sparing no detail" which may be crucial, for example, in a crime investigation.

Comment: Both Verbosity and Logorrhoea are about the sheer number of words being used. They don't need to be obvious words.

Comment: I would have to say that calling someone "Captain Obvious" is pretty offensive. There is a strong implication that they are too stupid to realise that what they are saying is obvious to others.

Answer (score 10):

I don't believe there's a single word that has the exact meaning you want, but the phrase "belaboring the obvious" is a classic idiom for your second case.

Comment: +1 for a great suggestion, I wanted to avoid the description "stating the obvious" because it lacks a certain negative connotation that I was needing. "Belaboring" conveys more acutely the sense I was wanting.

Answer (score 7):

*Redundant* is the word that you're looking for, according to Merriam-Webster.
*Redundant* means

- *exceeding what is necessary or normal*
- *superfluous*

So you can say:

> *Please could you be less redundant and get straight to the point?*

Comment: I find redundant implies duplication, not just over-abundance or pletoric (?)

Comment: Not really. The word redundant implies nothing about how obvious (or not) the information is.

Answer (score 7):

Stating the obvious is perhaps best stated as "self-evident." For example, "A street is better than a little trail to connect those two large neighborhoods."  "That's self-evident."

Answer (score 1):

I think a ***bromide*** would be apt for your query.

> Instead of offering an umbrella to her, the cheeky stranger offered
>   the bromide: "It's raining", much to her dismay.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for *belabor*, which means to redundantly or excessively state the obvious.

Comment: Don't you mean *belabor the obvious*?  Someone already suggested that phrase, however, so if you have nothing to add to it, there is no need for an answer.

Comment: @Danielδ: you can *belabour a point* (or even *labour it*.)

Comment: Not really. The word belabor implies nothing about how obvious (or not) the information is. You could belabor a very non-obvious point.

Answer (score -1):

*Platitude*, as in "He is full of platitudes"?

Comment: I think is more related to the tropes of cliché or Dutch Uncle (no offence intended); i.e. content rather than delivery.