# What's a positive phrase for "stating the obvious"?

Tags: word-choice

This is somewhat of a dual to [Word for "stating the obvious?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11087/word-for-stating-the-obvious), but what would be a good word selection to say that someone's point is obvious in hindsight, but without any sort of negative connotation that the idea is trivial?

> His idea to fund prevention versus treatment is [obvious in hindsight]

Comment: Not quite answering your question, but "common sense" is a related concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@pageman is on the right track, but here's how most people would phrase it:

> In retrospect, his idea to fund prevention instead of treatment was a good one.

Answer (score 4):

I would write "His idea to fund prevention versus treatment was prescient." Maybe loses the "obvious" connotation, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use plain or apparent.

"The value of his idea to fund prevention instead of treatment became plain."

Answer (score 1):

"Patently" is a good modifier for "obvious".

> patently obvious

The phrase still carries (for me) a negative connotation about the people who should have realized the point, but I think your concern was about the point itself seeming trivial.

Answer (score 0):

try [retrospectively](http://dictionary.sensagent.com/in+hindsight/en-en/):

Retrospectively, his idea to fund prevention versus treatment was good.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "vindicated by experience"?